# obtener imagen cada vez que la url se actualiza

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

tengo días buscando solucionar este problema pero los codigos que encuentro no me ayudan a solucionarlo...

Voy con la explicación:

1.- tengo este link https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2731376b4b16f4bfcba02dc571b

esta parte (ab67616d0000b2731376b4b16f4bfcba02dc571b) es una imagen jpg temporal, porque temporal, porque es el cover de una canción que está sonando, y cuando esta termina, ese codigo cambia por la imagen de la siguiente canción y asi cada vez que viene una nueva canción ese codigo cambia por una nueva imagen o cover del cantante.

EL resultado que busco, es obtener de ese link esa imagen cada vez que cambia...

No posteo codigo porque no se como se hace....

Tenia la idea de hacer el seguimiento a esta parte del link "https://i.scdn.co/image/" y que al agregarse la imagen, obtener el nuevo link y mostrarlo, para asi ver que cada vez que cambie el link con el codigo de la imagen, comparar y mostrar el nuevo contenido...

P.D.: no es que no me fui a google a conseguir la tarea, si, probe varios codigo que no me sirvieron o quede atascado en uno que solo detecta eol cambio del link pero mas nada...

este:

```
var oldURL = 'https://i.scdn.co/image/';
var currentURL = window.location.href;
function checkURLchange(currentURL){
if(currentURL != oldURL){
    alert("url changed!");
    oldURL = currentURL;
    console.log (oldURL);
}

oldURL = window.location.href;
setTimeout(function() {
    checkURLchange(window.location.href);
}, 1000);
```

}

checkURLchange();

pero no este no es el resultado que busco en el codigo: alert("url changed!");
sino este completo https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2731376b4b16f4bfcba02dc571b, cada vez que cambie y asi logro obtener la portada del titulo...

Tengo contratado un servidor streaming shoutcast 2.6v. la url envia la metadata completa (portada, titulo, canción), pero no se como obtenerla...

ya solucione lo del titulo y la cancion me falta esta portada... gracias por tomarse la molestia de leer mi enunciado...

este codigo me lo da el panel para insertar mis datos donde quiera, pero no me muestra nada, todo es null...

```
<?
```

// This is an example PHP script to get the JSON data sent from the SonicPanel.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$song = $data['song']; // Now Playing Song Arist - Title
$listeners = $data['listeners']; // Live Listners now listening to 
the radio.
$djstatus = $data['djstatus']; // true/false (string)
$djusername = $data['djusername']; // Online DJ username/false 
(string)
$art = $data['art']; // Now playing song cover art image, HD 
resolution.

// echo "Now Playing: $song <br><br> There are $listeners listeners
```

The album cover image url: $art";

print_r ($data); // Shows complete JSON encoded data.

// Any data provided on this page can be used as you like.
?>

Comment: El problema que veo es que precisamente no sabes cuándo cambia la URL o cómo estará conformada, quiero decir, no existe una ruta "mágica" que te redireccione a la URL correcta. Por lo que entonces me hace más sentido que si sabes que la URL viene en la metadata, la trates de obtener de ahí. ¿Podrías decir en dónde contrataste el servicio? Tal vez tengan algo de documentación que pueda ser de ayuda.

Comment: Saludos ricardo,  el servicio es desonic panel hosting manager, pero me lo contrate a través de serivicio hosting... Precisamente como no se cuando cambia, necesito supervisar el cambio con un intervalo, para que cuando cambie el link obtener el nuevo cambio y mostrar... al menos sé que esa ruta es la que cambia cada vez que suena una nueva canción y en ese link recibe la imagen de la cancíón que suena. saludos. gracias por contestar

Answer (score 1):

Quizás ésto te de la idea que necesitas:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<title>Mostrar_imagen_por_url</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#CCCCFF">


    <!-- Inicio del contenedor de entrada -->
<!-- ∞∞——∞∞——∞—∞——∞∞——∞∞ -->
    <div style="width:280px;
 margin:2px; border-radius:6px; padding:8px;
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
 background-color:#200000; text-align: center; color:white;"
onClick="busqueda('texto');">
<!-- ———————————————— -->

<!-- Aquí se ingresa la url mediante una función, 
ejemplo: texto.value = "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2731376b4b16f4bfcba02dc571b" 
coloqué una por default pero se cambia con muestreos -->

  <input type="text" id="texto" value="http://www.gatospedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/domestico-pelo-corto.jpg"
style="border-radius:6px; border:2px solid; border-color:gold;">
</div>
    <!-- Final del contenedor -->
<!-- ============================ -->
<br />


<!-- Ejemplo de mostrar la imagen de la url -->
<img id="mostrar" border="1" src="" width="300px"
height="auto" alt="Cargando..." />

<script>
// Tomas el **id** donde mostrar
    var mostrar = document.getElementById('mostrar');

// Creas la función de muestreo
function busqueda(texto)
{
// Y tomas **id** mas **value** de la entrada de url; o un método similar
    var enlace = document.getElementById(texto).value;

// Y lo aplicas cada 500 ms
    mostrar.src = enlace;

// Mediante
    setTimeout("busqueda('texto');", 500);
}
// Lo activas al cargar la página
busqueda('texto');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

PD: Espero te ayude. No entiendo el por qué dices `no saber postear códigos`, posteaste uno bastante bien.

Comment: gracias Triplex, probaré a ver que resulta, escribi mal, era que no tenia algun codigo que haya ensayado para hacer pruebas de lo que buscaba, solo ese que coloque pero no dió resultado, saludos y exitos

Comment: La idea esta buena, el problema que encuentro es como saber cuando esta parte de la url cambie: (ab67616d0000b2731376b4b16f4bfcba02dc571b) por otra...

Comment: @Francisco Toro, si lo único que cambia es esa parte, o cualquier otra que cambie; si usas una variable para guardar el valor de la que sería: `lastURL` y otra para "rastrear" el cambio como un `currentURL`, solo tienes que comparar ambas e if ( no iguales ) pues entonces function, ¿Captas? Que te de la nueva imagen y, además; actualice a `lastURL` para que el comparador no se dispare. Éxitos para ti también, y gracias

Comment: bueno me comunique con el soporte del panel, y me responden que van a actulizar el panel para que me muestre la parte de los metadatos incluido la imagen... bueee, solo me queda esperar que actualicen y usarlo.... gracias por el apoyo Triple. te dejaré un like arriba por el apoyo... exitos bro. y de hecho la solución realmente es abrir una cuenta spotify y usar las metadatas de spotify...